# Use textfield instead of searchbar in GMSAutocomplete in a same manner

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am using google Place Autocomplete API, i need to add UITextField instead of UISearchBar with the same functionality. here is the working code with UISearchBar which i get from https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete. I will add textfield and tableview myself, if someone just help me to get array of addresses from any keyword of searching. like from string (of keyword) to array(predicted places).

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var resultsViewController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController?
var searchController: UISearchController?
var resultView: UITextView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    resultsViewController = GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()
    resultsViewController?.delegate = self

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsViewController)
    searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = resultsViewController

    let subView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 65.0, 350.0, 45.0))

    subView.addSubview((searchController?.searchBar)!)
    self.view.addSubview(subView)
    searchController?.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
}
}

extension ViewController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewControllerDelegate {
func resultsController(resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,
    didAutocompleteWithPlace place: GMSPlace) {
        searchController?.active = false
        print("Place name: ", place.name)
        print("Place address: ", place.formattedAddress!)
}

func resultsController(resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,
    didFailAutocompleteWithError error: NSError){
        print("Error: ", error.description)
}

func didRequestAutocompletePredictionsForResultsController(resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
}

func didUpdateAutocompletePredictionsForResultsController(resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
}
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Integrate your GPA(Google Places API). POD files are :

```
pod 'GooglePlaces'
pod 'GooglePlacePicker'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
```

At first, provide your KEY to AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("Your KEY")
        return true
    }
```

At first, take a text field and a table view. Then add these line to your ViewController.swift file and hook the textField and tableView and finally run it.

```
    import UIKit
    import GooglePlaces

    class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet weak var PlaceTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var tableData=[String]()

    var fetcher: GMSAutocompleteFetcher?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []

        // Set bounds to inner-west Sydney Australia.
        let neBoundsCorner = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.843366,
                                                    longitude: 151.134002)
        let swBoundsCorner = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.875725,
                                                    longitude: 151.200349)
        let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: neBoundsCorner,
                                         coordinate: swBoundsCorner)

        // Set up the autocomplete filter.
        let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
        filter.type = .establishment

        // Create the fetcher.
        fetcher = GMSAutocompleteFetcher(bounds: bounds, filter: filter)
        fetcher?.delegate = self as! GMSAutocompleteFetcherDelegate

        PlaceTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.textFieldDidChanged(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // MARK: -UITextField Action

    @objc func textFieldDidChanged(_ textField:UITextField ){
        print(PlaceTextField.text!)
        fetcher?.sourceTextHasChanged(PlaceTextField.text!)
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var section = indexPath.section

        var row = indexPath.row

        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier:"addCategoryCell")

        cell.selectionStyle =  UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)

        cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController: GMSAutocompleteFetcherDelegate {
    func didAutocomplete(with predictions: [GMSAutocompletePrediction]) {
        tableData.removeAll()

        for prediction in predictions {

            tableData.append(prediction.attributedPrimaryText.string)

            //print("\n",prediction.attributedFullText.string)
            //print("\n",prediction.attributedPrimaryText.string)
            //print("\n********")
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func didFailAutocompleteWithError(_ error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: How to get coordinate of the selected place from prediction object?

Comment: I just implemented this and tried to search for a specific address in Canada but it does not work. It only shows the name of places like airport names, or a restaurant name but no address specific. How can I populate the address specifically with your code here?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a UITextField and your own UITableView in place of a UISearchController, then it's easier to use the [GMSAutocompleteTableDataSource](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_autocomplete_table_data_source) class directly.

One of the code samples for the GoogleMaps Cocoapod shows how to do this. Look for the file `SDKDemoAutocompleteWithTextFieldController` in the `Pods/GoogleMaps/GoogleMapsSDKDemos/SDKDemos/PlacesSamples` directory of your project if you've installed the pod, or run `pod try GoogleMaps` to download the samples.

Answer (score 0):

//In your View Controller there TextField and TableView Setup

```
import UIKit
import GooglePlaces

class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var table1: UITableView!

    var tableData = [String]()

    var fetcher: GMSAutocompleteFetcher?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []

        let nsBoundsCorner = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 20.5937, longitude: 78.9629)

        let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: nsBoundsCorner, coordinate: nsBoundsCorner)

        let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
        filter.type = .establishment

        fetcher  = GMSAutocompleteFetcher(bounds: bounds, filter: filter)
        fetcher?.delegate = self

        txtField?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(textField:)),for: .editingChanged)

        table1.delegate = self
        table1.dataSource = self

        self.table1.reloadData()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @objc func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
            fetcher?.sourceTextHasChanged(txtField.text!)
        }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return tableData.count
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var section = indexPath.section
        var row = indexPath.row

        let cell1 : UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell1")

        cell1.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
        cell1.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell1.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell1.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
        cell1.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
        cell1.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)

        cell1.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
        return cell1
    }



//    extension TableViewController: GMSAutocompleteFetcherDelegate {
//
//        func didAutocompleteWithPredictions(predictions: [GMSAutocompletePrediction]) {
//
//            tableData.removeAll()
//
//            for prediction in predictions {
//
//                tableData.append(prediction.attributedPrimaryText.string)
//
//            }
//
//            table1.reloadData()
//        }
//
//    }



    @IBAction func textField1(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}

extension TableViewController: GMSAutocompleteFetcherDelegate {


    func didAutocomplete(with predictions: [GMSAutocompletePrediction]) {

        tableData.removeAll()

        for prediction in predictions{

            tableData.append(prediction.attributedFullText.string)

        }
        table1.reloadData()
    }

    func didFailAutocompleteWithError(_ error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }



}
```

// Also Setup App delegate

```
import UIKit
import GooglePlaces
import GoogleMaps
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

////        [GMSPlacesClient provideAPIKey:...]
//        [GMSPlacesClient .provideAPIKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")]

        GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("xxxxxxx")
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("xxxxxxxxxx")

        return true
    }
}
```

[image]