# Google map autocomplete address

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-api-3

I am making app where i am using google map, in main page there is one text box where i am typing address but its opening full table with search result and i want to show result table below of that text box.

```
extension HomeLocationVC: GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate{


// Handle the user's selection.
func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {


    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: place.coordinate.latitude, longitude: place.coordinate.longitude)
    let position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(10, 10)

    self.addressTextField.text = String(describing: place.formattedAddress!)
    print("Place name: \(place.name)")
    print("Place address: \(String(describing: place.formattedAddress))")
    print("Place attributions: \(String(describing: place.attributions))")

    camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (place.coordinate.latitude),
                                      longitude: (place.coordinate.longitude),
                                      zoom: zoomLevel)

    self.mapView.clear()
    self.marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
    self.marker.position = center
    self.marker.title = String(describing: place.formattedAddress!)
    self.marker.map   = self.mapView
    self.marker.isTappable = true
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error) {
    // TODO: handle the error.
    print("Error: \(error)")
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// User cancelled the operation.
func wasCancelled(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    print("Autocomplete was cancelled.")
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


}

 @IBAction func changeValue(_ sender: UITextField) {

    let acController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
    acController.delegate = self
    present(acController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Please review this link it will help u https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete

Comment: Please visit this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35862490/use-textfield-instead-of-searchbar-in-gmsautocomplete-in-a-same-manner